# PostgreSQL Custom not null constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to add a NOT NULL contstraint to one of my table fields but only when another field has a certain value.

So I have a `services` table:

```
services:
 - id
 - professional_id
 - is_master
```

I want to write a SQL constraint that whenever `is_master` is false `professional_id` cannot be null. I've tried things like:

```
CREATE TABLE "services" (
    "id" text NOT NULL,
    "professional_id" text REFERENCES professionals ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    EXCLUDE USING gist (
        professional_id WITH =,
    ) WHERE (NOT is_master),
    "is_master" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

What is the correct way to write this SQL?

Comment: Create a trigger to achieve that https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: `check (not is_master and professional_id is not null)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `check` constraint.  A simple one is:

```
constraint chk_services_master_professions
    check (is_master or professional_id is not null)
```

Note:  This version assumes that `is_master` is never `NULL` -- or that `NULL` is equivalent to "false".

Comment: This is def the cleanest one but I had already accepted the other answer before seeing this.

Comment: @Rodrigo: Are you aware that you can switch the chosen answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
check (not is_master and professional_id is not null or is_master)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CHECK` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE "services" (
    "id" text NOT NULL,
    "professional_id" text 
       CHECK (CASE WHEN "is_master" IS FALSE AND "professional_id" IS NULL 
              THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE END), -- and rest of FK
    "is_master" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/ZVZ49446)**

```
INSERT INTO services
VALUES (1,1, FALSE);

INSERT INTO services
VALUES (2,1, true);

INSERT INTO services
VALUES (3, null, true);

INSERT INTO services
VALUES (4, null, false);
```

> 23514: new row for relation "services" violates check constraint "services_check"